# Retrieving Multimedia Component from TBB Parameter

Tags: tom.net

I am trying to grab a multimedia component which is linked as a parameter to a TBB. Typically I am just grabbing strings passed in as parameters such as below, however I am unable to find a way to do the same for components.

```
String value = package.GetValue("inputValue");
```

I have tried to get the value from the properties (as shown below), with no luck.

```
string xsltComponentId = xsltMMComponentItem.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyTcmUri];
Component xsltMMComponent = (Component)engine.GetObject(xsltComponentId);
```

Also tried to get it AsSource:

```
string xsltComponentId = xsltMMComponentItem.GetAsSource().GetValue("ID");
Component xsltMMComponent = (Component)engine.GetObject(xsltComponentId);
```

If someone could give me some guidance as to how I can get the component link, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a component is linked as a parameter you never get the item as a component object, using `Package.GetValue("name in schema")` will return the string ID of the component.

From there you can use the `engine.GetObject(tcmid)` to get the object.

Hope this helps xxx

Comment: whoops didn't meant to add some kisses to the end of this answer - ah well it's good to spread some love into the community :)

Answer (score 2):

Do this way:

```
String ID = Package.GetValue("inputValue");
Component component = (Component)mEngine.GetObject(ID);
```